# Keycloak get token using grant type password always return 401 error

Tags: postman, keycloak

Hello i try do request get token from keycloak. I poison request with help postman.
I am sending the request in this form.
POST http://localhost:8484/auth/realms/realm-name/protocol/openid-connect/token

Headers:

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body x-www-form-urlencoded:

client_id: my-client

username: username

password: password

grant_type: password

client_secret: secret_client

In response i get this message.
 `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid user credentials"}`
I always return this error, but username and password are correct.
What could this be related to? Can i see over details error description? And what didn't i do correct?

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.